# removeAttr() not applied?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zepto

I'm using zepto.js for my current project which has the same `removeAttr()` method as jquery has.

i'm applying a `margin-top` to a bunch of elements – works fine.

```
var $apply = $('aside[role="sub"], aside[role="event-info"], aside[role="attend"]');
$apply.css('margin-top', '100px'); //works fine
```

However I also need to remove it again in a resize-event.

```
if ( $(window).width() <= 984 ) {
    //$apply.removeAttr('style'); //doesn't take effect
    $apply.css('margin-top', '0'); //works fine
    console.log('< 984');       
}
```

So i'm able to set the `margin-top` back to `0` but can't completely remove the style attribute from the selector.

Any ideas why? I don't get any erros, it just doesn't take effect.

Comment: You can't remove the "style" property of a DOM element.  (It's a property, not an attribute.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to remove it, is by not setting a value when using the `.css`.

```
$apply.css('margin-top', ''); // remove property
```

> When a value for a property is empty, that property is removed.

Read more [here](http://zeptojs.com/#css).

Comment: I presume that if there was a margin before the other was explicitly set that it would need to go back to this. I believe the above code wouldn't do that (though I may be wrong)...

Comment: Yes, this would simply remove the attribute, just as the question requested. Reverting to a previous value would be a different scenario.

Answer (score 3):

From http://api.jquery.com/css/

> **Setting the value of a style property to an empty string — e.g.
>   $('#mydiv').css('color', '') — removes that property from an element**
>   if it has already been directly applied, whether in the HTML style
>   attribute, through jQuery's .css() method, or through direct DOM
>   manipulation of the style property. *It does not, however, remove a
>   style that has been applied with a CSS rule in a stylesheet or 
>   element.*

So you can use `$apply.css('margin-top', '')` to remove the `margin-top` style.

Use `.removeClass()` to remove all styles from the element.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend creating a CSS class that you add and remove instead.
This way you can easily modify the margin value in one location and not have to change it in multiple locations.

CSS:

```
.myMargin { margin-top : 100px; }
```

JS:

```
var $apply = $('aside[role="sub"], aside[role="event-info"], aside[role="attend"]');
$apply.addClass("myMargin");
```

In the resize event:

```
if ( $(window).width() <= 984 ) {
    $apply.removeClass("myMargin");
    console.log('< 984');       
}
```